# Ubuntu Aquaris System Settings > Updates

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, webapps, phone

When I tap the "Updates" in "System Settings" it shows 5 items for updating, BBC Sport, webapp-twitter, Calculator, Tagger and Music.

If I tap the "Install 5 updates" button all 5 indicate "Downloading" but nothing ever happens, they all stay at 0%.

For info "Auto download" "When on wi-fi" is selected" and it

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes happens. A possible solution is removing and readding your Ubuntu One account.

To do that, please go to `System settings` -> `Accounts`, select your Ubuntu One account, click on `Remove account` and then readd it.

After that, try again to download updates.